# How can I make a global variable inside of a function?

Tags: javascript

In other languages (like C++ or C#) I can make a public variable inside of a class. I want to make a global variable inside of a function.

Example:

```
let idk = function(){
    let num = 5;
};

// use the variable in global scope

console.log(num);
```

Comment: Leave the `let` off `let num = 5;`, but that's usually an anti-pattern.

Comment: Any good tutorial on variable scoping in javascript would explain different scenarios to you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declare a global variable from inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608656/declare-a-global-variable-from-inside-a-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expose it with `window` - `window.num = 5` if you are in a browser.

Or in Node, use `global` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the variable outside without assigning to it, then assign to the variable inside without declaring it:

```
let num;

let idk = function () {
    num = 5;
};

// use the variable in global scope

console.log(num);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a global variable within a function since the scope of any variable created  within a function  cannot be global. But you can set value to a global variable from within the function. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

if your program running on the browser than You can use like this

```
    <script>
function foo() {
    window.yourGlobalVariable = ...;
}
</script>
```

Or you can declire the variable oursite of the funciton and you can use it inside of the function

```
<script>
var globalVariable;
    function bar() {
        globalVariable = "set value into the global variable";
    }
</script>
```